# Simulating possibly correlated processes of different orders of integration

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, vector-autoregression

Given historical data on 6 macroeconomic time series, I am trying to build a model for the purposes of forecasting and simulating. A plot of the (standardised) series is below.

[image]

A natural choice for such a model is a VAR. I fit a VAR in differences, and it produced reasonable forecasts/simulations for some time series and completely crazy ones for others. I decided to run `auto_arima` as a sanity check on the individual series and obtained the following "best" models for my 6 time series:

- ARIMA(2,2,3)
- ARIMA(0,2,1)
- ARIMA(2,1,3) + intercept
- ARIMA(0,1,0) + intercept
- ARIMA(0,1,0) + intercept
- ARIMA(1,2,4)

It turns out I was too hasty in fitting a VAR in differences: my time series have different orders of integration, and some moreover include moving average components.

**Q.** How would you proceed in this situation?

My idea is as follows. Since VARMA models [aren't straightforward to estimate](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_varmax.html#:%7E:text=Although%20the%20model,provide%20useful%20information.), I stick with the individual ARIMA models, but n order to ensure that consistent simulations, I draw samples from a multivariate normal with covariance matrix equal to the covariance matrix of the residuals from the six ARIMA models.

**Q.** Is this a reasonable strategy? How could I do better? Where could it go wrong?

Comment: Could you include a plot of your 6 series?

Comment: @RichardHardy Done.